# MongoDB doen't work after update OSX to Catalina

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal

Now, when I try to launch my MongoDB application by running:

```
sudo mongod
```

I get the following error

```
2019-11-24T01:49:55.247-0300 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-11-24T01:49:55.256-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=91533 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=MacBook-Pro-de-Sebastian.local
2019-11-24T01:49:55.256-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.1
2019-11-24T01:49:55.256-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: edf6d45851c0b9ee15548f0f847df141764a317e
2019-11-24T01:49:55.256-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-11-24T01:49:55.256-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-11-24T01:49:55.256-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-11-24T01:49:55.256-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-11-24T01:49:55.256-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-11-24T01:49:55.256-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-11-24T01:49:55.257-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2019-11-24T01:49:55.257-0300 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-11-24T01:49:55.257-0300 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-11-24T01:49:55.257-0300 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2019-11-24T01:49:55.257-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-11-24T01:49:55.257-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

please guys, help !!